# trying to play .wav file which is in Resources folder, its there but visual studio sais it isn't!

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to play L1.wav which is in my resources folder.  Previously I have pulled images from the resources file using the line btc.Properties.Resources.noImg which worked perfectly but if I try and do the same for the wav file I get a '...does not contain a definition for L1.  Its there, works fine if I double click it.  How do I get it to work?

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = btc.Properties.Resources.L1;
player.play();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SoundLocation property requires a string that contains a file path or a URL.  The resource you added is however returned as a Stream if it was a .wav file.  You should have gotten a compile error message, saying that it can't convert an UnmanagedMemoryStream to a string.

This code worked well on my machine:

```
        System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
        player.Stream = Properties.Resources.test;
        player.Play();
```

What *btc* means in your source code is quite mysterious and possibly the real source of the compiler error message you quoted.

Comment: btc is the project name.  I tried this and am still getting the same error which is that the resources file does not contain a definition for L1 which is the wav file.  Very odd.

Comment: Why are you prefixing the project name?  Where does the resource actually live?  Have you added it to the correct project?

Comment: the project name is not necessary and I get the same error if I do not include it and do as you did and just type Properties.Resources.L1.  And yes I have added it to the correct project.  As I have said, I have added jpg files to the resources folder and have no problem accessing them in exactly the same manner.

Comment: I deleted the .wav files and then added one back.  I did the same with a jpg file.  The jpg file showed up fine but the .wav file did not, I am wondering if there is something to do with the .wav files themselves which is preventing the app from recognizing them.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care about the .wav file when it looks for "L1".  Post a screen shot of the Resources tab view.

Comment: I added another resx file called sounds and now it works!  My question is now what if I want to build a string to call the file because the one played is dependent on a few factors.  For instance the current location (t_loci = 23) so the correct file would be 'L23' but now using a stream I am not sure how to get to that point?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"location of the file.wav");
             player.Play();

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream audio = <assembly>.Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("notify.wav");
        SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(audio);
        player.Play();
```

With simplicity...

Answer (score 0):

```
(new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.L1)).Play();
```

Its as simple as that.